# Learning the meaning of " :?: " operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parametric-polymorphism, type-constructor

I'm learning Haskell and I just saw this weird data structure in my book, it looks like this: `data ListaOrd a = a :?: (ListaOrd a) | Nulo deriving Show`. It was said that this supposed to represent an ordered list, but I don't think I really understood it. My question is, what is the meaning of " :?: " symbol in that code?

Comment: I assume that there is `data` in front of that line?

Comment: Yeah, you're right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, what is the meaning of `:?:`

You are here **defining** a data constructor that is the `:?:` operator. Indeed, in GHCi you can query the type of the `(:?:)` function:

```
:t (:?:)
(:?:) :: a -> ListaOrd a -> ListaOrd
```

It is thus exactly the same as if you would have used another name, like:

```
data ListaOrd a = Conso a (ListaOrd a) | Nulo deriving Show
```

But here we define a data constructor with name `(:?:)` that can be used with operator syntax as well. In fact you likely already used such data constructor(s). For example `(:)` is a data constructor for a list.